# Regex: Find if string contains whole word or is a prefix

Tags: python, regex

I've been using an awesome function i've found here:

```
def word_in_text(word, text):
    pattern = r'(^|[^\w]){}([^\w]|$)'.format(word)
    pattern = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    matches = re.search(pattern, text)
    return bool(matches)
```

It works flawlessly in finding an exact match of a word in a text, but i would need it to also  match if it's plural or is the prefix of a word.
Example:

apple would also match apples

But because I don't fully understand this regex expression I'm having trouble changing it.

Comment: Just remove the `([^\w]|$)` from the end of the regex as that is what forces the match to end at a word boundary. Note you can simplify `(^|[^\w])` to `\b`.

Comment: If you need help understanding Regular Expressions, plug in that value into an online tester such as [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZOjpEP1t68Mophw-
) or [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tixbQr/1). The `[^w]` is the same as `\W` and is the same as any non-word character (not [a-zA-Z_0-9]).

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick! That fixed it! Also changed it to \b and worked great